# Помогите сформулировать алгоритм

Tags: jquery, алгоритм, html, css, javascript

Имеется картинка, размеры могут быть любые. Имеется область, полотно, canvas, если понятнее. Картинка может быть как больше заданной области, так и меньше, причем в разные оси, то есть картинка может быть по ширине больше области, но по высоте меньше ее, и наоборот. Если картинку разместить в этой области, то все, что выходит за ее границы будет скрыто. Задача состоит в том, чтобы масштабировать картинку с сохранением пропорций так, чтобы она заняла всю область полностью, в области пустых пространств быть не должно. Для решения есть два пути - масштабировать картинку по ширине области, или по высоте, как в размеры большие этой области, так и в размеры меньшие этой области, пусть заведомо известно, что пропорции картинки сохранятся при масштабировании и вся задача, таким образом, сводится к тому, чтобы правильно определить в сторону какой оси нужно масштабировать картинку (по ширине области или по длине). Известны ширина и длина картинки, ширина и длина области. То есть если картинка по ширине больше области, но по высоте меньше ее, то в данном случае мы масштабируем по высоте, так как в обратном случае на области будет пустое пространство. Или если картинка по ширине меньше области, но по высоте больше, то масштабируем по ширине, так как в обратном случае будет пустая область в пространстве. Примеры:

> Ширина картинки - 300 пикселов
>   Высота картинки - 420 пикселов
>   Ширина области - 220 пикселов
>   Высота области - 120 пикселов
>   Решение - масштабируем по ширине области
>
> Ширина картинки - 300 пикселов
>   Высота картинки - 420 пикселов
>   Ширина области - 220 пикселов
>   Высота области - 420 пикселов
>   Решение - масштабируем по высоте области
>
> Ширина картинки - 300 пикселов
>   Высота картинки - 420 пикселов
>   Ширина области - 220 пикселов
>   Высота области - 320 пикселов
>   Решение - масштабируем по высоте области
>
> Ширина картинки - 300 пикселов
>   Высота картинки - 420 пикселов
>   Ширина области - 220 пикселов
>   Высота области - 220 пикселов
>   Решение - масштабируем по ширине области

Если кому-то потребуется конкретика: пишу алгоритм масштабирования картинки на js в размер фиксированного div'a, с сохранением пропорций. Визуально я понимаю куда надо двигаться, да вот алгоритм из этого вывести не могу, голова не варит...

Comment: Не могу сообразить, что из чего вычитать, что к чему прибавлять, что с чем сравнивать, т.е. не вижу математической модели, хотя сам то я себя на глупости не замечал, но тут возникли трудности...

Comment: А области и картинка прямоугольные? Т.е. не сложной формы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что мешает проверять соотношения параметров? Например,

```
if((ширина_картинки / ширина_блока) > 1){
    // ширина картинки больше блока
}
// "< 1" - меньше, "== 1" - одинаково
```

Так же и высоту проверить. А дальше принять решение в зависимости от результата. Кроме того, надо учесть, если оба параметра изображения больше или меньше параметров картинки.

P.S. Набросал вам [примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/3AZK8/1/). Вроде бы разложил всё по полочкам (*мог, конечно, чего-нить не учесть*). Изменяйте размеры блока в css и смотрите результат.

Comment: Ну тут придется рассматривать частные случаи... 
Решил проблему более изящно:
    if (wRatio > hRatio)
2 выхода - либо в ширь, либо в высь )